# The \"path\" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, file

I am trying to get a file from reactjs and send as param to Node.js backend for processing in an API. But it gives me this error. Here is the code:

```
const FormData = require("form-data");
    const fs = require("fs");
    const model = "tr-8";
    const formd = new FormData();
    const { voice } = req.body;
    const file = voice;
    const timeout = 360000;
    formd.append("model", model);
    formd.append("files[]", fs.createReadStream(voice, { autoClose: true }));
    const request = formd.submit(
      `${Process.env.API}` + model,
      function (err, rs) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("formd.submit error " + voice);

          console.log(err);
        }

        if (rs) {
          var resp = Buffer.from([]);

          rs.on("error", function (err) {
            console.log("formd.submit on error " + voice);

            console.log(err);
          });

          rs.on("close", function () {
            console.log("close " + voice);
          });

          rs.on("data", function (chunk) {
            resp = Buffer.concat([resp, chunk]);
          });

          rs.on("end", function () {
            console.log("end " + voice);

            const resputf8 = resp.toString("utf8");

            const recognitionResult = JSON.parse(resputf8);

            const speech = recognitionResult.JsonResult;

            if (speech.error) {
              console.log("transcript error " + speech.error + " " + voice);
            } else {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(speech, null, 2));
            }
          });
        }
      }
    );
```

And In the frontend, I send the file like that:

```
<Input type="file" name="voice" />
```

This is my error code:

```
    at ReadStream._construct (node:internal/fs/streams:64:17)
    at constructNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:288:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
```

How can i prevent this error?

Comment: Can you add the error stack details in the question code?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara  i 've added the error code

Comment: The problem is in  ```const { voice } = req.body;```
The error come from voice being undefined. 
Are you using bodyparser and multer?

Comment: @Mehrdad i don't use bodyParser becuz it is deprecated

Comment: @nilufer17 express.urlencoded then.
log the voice, is it defined?

Comment: I am using like you've told me. But the voice is not defined

Comment: You also need multer for file processing

Comment: @Mehrdad should i use the multer on frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need multer for multipart files and uploads. In frontend add this

```
<form action="/voice" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="voice" />
</form>
```

and in backend,

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

app.post('/voice', upload.single('voice'), function (req, res, next) {
    // req.file is the `voice` file
    const  voice  = req.file
    // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```